# How can I delete the data from a json server in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, localhost, json-server

Link of the JSON data https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.e09cb2f612284a47a28c71a2c813da80
How can I delete subjectname from JSON data
my code is here
http://localhost:3003/CourseList is my local JSON server

```
 const deleteSub = async id => {
        try{
          const data = await axios.get("http://localhost:3003/CourseList")
          //How should I map and delete the subname ???? 
        }
        catch(err){
          console.log(err.message)
        }
      };
```

Comment: Have you tried looping the json with `.forEach` and using `delete` keyword to delete the key you want ?

Comment: What JSON? Please may you include all the relevant code _in the question itself_ making sure it is a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use .filter method to do this

```
const deleteSub = async id => {
        try{
          const data = await axios.get("http://localhost:3003/CourseList")
          const filteredData = data.filter(d => d.id !== id)
          console.log(filteredData)
        }
        catch(err){
          console.log(err.message)
        }
};
```

Comment: Hi, seems like OP's question was to delete a particular key rather than filter entire objects.